# what allows multiple selections in facets on commerce kickstart?

Tags: commerce, blocks, search

can someone tell me where the setting is to keep all the choices displayed after a selection is made in a facet block if my search is for a color say

```
[]Red
[]Green
[]Blue
[]Orange
[]Purple
```

I'd like to be able to select both red and green or red and blue etc etc...
I have hunted for a setting to keep the options in the blocks screen, facets screen (probably missed it somewhere in all the options), and tried to compare a commerce kickstart install with mine.